# EF 6 Code First __MigrationHistory in dbo schema by default

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am new to Code first Entity framework, when logging into the database after running my app for the first time I got a little confused when I saw the "__MigrationHistory" table.

I now understand the need for this table, but do not like it being in the standard dbo schema within the user table, I think its obtrusive and a risk.

My first thought was to move it to the system folder. When researching how to achieve this within the EF context all I could find is how to move it from system to dbo.

I now get the feeling __MigrationHistory should by default be created within the system folder... is this the case?

How can I configure my context to manage/reference the migration history table within the system folder by default?

Here is my context, am I doing something wrong or missing some configuration?

```
public class MyContext : DbContext, IDataContext
{
    public IDbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }

    public MyContext()
        : base("ConnectionString")
    {

    }

    public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Comment: It actually used to be in the System folder by default but this behaviour was changed in EF 6.

Answer (score 2):

There is a technique for moving __MigrationHistory. That table has it's own context ([System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.history.historycontext(v=vs.113).aspx)) that you can override:

```
public class MyHistoryContext : HistoryContext 
{ 
    public MyHistoryContext(DbConnection dbConnection, string defaultSchema) 
        : base(dbConnection, defaultSchema) 
    { 
    } 

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    { 
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); 
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().ToTable(tableName: "MigrationHistory", schemaName: "admin"); 
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(p => p.MigrationId).HasColumnName("Migration_ID"); 
    } 
}
```

Then you need to [register](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbconfiguration.sethistorycontext(v=vs.113).aspx) it:

```
public class ModelConfiguration : DbConfiguration 
{ 
    public ModelConfiguration() 
    { 
        this.SetHistoryContext("System.Data.SqlClient", 
            (connection, defaultSchema) => new MyHistoryContext(connection, defaultSchema)); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try executing `EXEC sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject __MigrationHistory` in your seed method using `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand();`

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("YourSchema");` to your context's `OnModelCreating` will do the trick.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }

        public MyContext () : base("ConnectionString"){}

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("YourSchema");
        }

    }
```