# Should I use different migration tables for each SQL schema?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

My project is working against an existing DB a default dbo schema, and I have created a separate schema for a new module I am building. I have a created a code first and generated some objects from the existing DB in my new code first domain model. I have created an empty first Migration and updated the DB. Now I have created a new table for my new schema using the below line:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<newTblClass>().ToTable("newTblClass", "newSchema");
```

And then I created a new migration and updated the DB.
In my DB I noticed my migrations were created on table dbo.__MigrationHistory.
Is this the right way to go? or should I use a separate migration table for each schema? and if so how?

Comment: EF store mistration history on that table. Having all migration record in one table is good thing. Leave as it is.

Comment: If you want a separate migration per schema, you would need to create a context for each. If you want to move __MigrationHistory to a different schema, there is a [technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355352/ef-6-code-first-migrationhistory-in-dbo-schema-by-default) for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are two way migration . First way is adding new for each schema changing. second way is automaticly creating migration.

if you want  return every changing you can use first way.

when make change your schema you should do that.
[image]

Displaying the Reminder
We write Enable-Migrations
[image]

after that, To add FirtsMigration and other Migrations, the NugetPackage Console
   We are writing Add-Migration FirstMigration

[image]

This way, our Migration Folder and Configiration class will be created spontaneously.